# What is the syntax of the enhanced for loop in Java?

Tags: java, foreach

I have been asked to use the enhanced `for` loop in my coding.

I have only been taught how to use traditional `for` loops, and as such don't know about the differences between it and the enhanced `for` loop.

**How does an enhanced `for` loop differ from a traditional `for` loop in Java?**

Are there any intricacies that I should look out for which tutorials tend not to mention?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: Although, if user1920811 had researched it and had found the answer really easily online and so hadn't asked this question I wouldn't have been able to find the exact syntax I required as the second link on google

Comment: 12 people upvoted this, and 21 its answer. Perhaps this should be reopened? I figured that questions that so completely go against the site that they are voted closed would not have such a positive community response.

Comment: @BenC.R.Leggiero 14 people upvoted this, and 22 its answer. Perhaps this should be reopened? I figured that questions that so completely go against the site that they are voted closed would not have such a positive community response.

Comment: Yes, please re-open this, user1920811 just asked about the syntax. Often I find stackoverflow questions contain more information than the tutorials posted online

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Enhanced for loop:

```
for (String element : array) {

    // rest of code handling current element
}
```

Traditional for loop equivalent:

```
for (int i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
    String element = array[i]; 

    // rest of code handling current element
}
```

Take a look at these forums: https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with

http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/the-enhanced-for-loop.html

Comment: But...links are bad, pa!  Best get to the gallows for'ta meet yer maker.

Answer (score 10):

An enhanced `for` loop is just limiting the number of parameters inside the parenthesis.

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(myArray[i]);
}
```

Can be written as:

```
for (int myValue : myArray) {
    System.out.println(myValue);
}
```

Comment: A note: traditional `for` loops can also do more. Enhanced ones are solely for iterating through an array or a class that implements `Iterable`. Traditional `for` loops can also be used to loop exactly `n` times (`for(int i=0; i<n; i++)`), loop infinitely (`for(;;)`), to abuse capabilities (`for(String name="me"; conn.isOpen(); System.out.println("hello!"))`), and many other such things.

Comment: The enhanced for-lops are only good for iteration. If you need the index, or want to do hacks and/or abuse capabilities, the traditional for-loops is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

1. Enhanced For Loop (Java)

```
for (Object obj : list);
```

2. Enhanced For Each in arraylist (Java)

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
list.forEach((n) -> System.out.println(n));
```