# method next() of an iterator

Tags: java, iterator

When I obtain iterator over an ArrayList and use the method next() on it,
does it return only next element or it return and remove elements from the iterator.
like

```
Iterator i = list.iterator();
while(i.hasNext())
    System.out.print(i.next()+" ");
```

Comment: Don't worry, remove() remove.

Comment: Maybe after the iteration? not during the iiteration. Can you answer this "mini" question?

Comment: Yes, after iteration i.hasNext() return false

Comment: Use ArrayList in an enhanced for loop, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685305/what-is-the-syntax-of-enhanced-for-loop-in-java

Answer (score 5):

Calling next() just moves a pointer to the next element 
and returns the element. It does not remove any elements.

For more details see here.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator#Java

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html

Iterators also have a remove() method. That method removes elements.