# For loop java query

Tags: java, string, for-loop

I have a question about for loops in java. I understand how for loops work an using the format :

```
for(initialize variable : condition : counter){}
```

My problem is in one of my lectures it says:

```
 for(String s : str){.....}
```

How come this doesn't need a counter? 
What is str?

Comment: This is an enhanced for loop, or a "for each" loop: https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with str should be a collection of strings in your example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an enhanced for loop, or a "for each" loop. It iterates over all the elements of `str`, which is probably a Collection of Strings in your example, or an Array of Strings.

Read [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with) for more details.

For example, instead of writing this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(myArray[i]);
}
```

you can write its equivalent:

```
for (int myValue : myArray) {
    System.out.println(myValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is an enhanced for loop that iterates through every element in the Collection. It doesn't stop until it is has hit the last element or encounters a `break;`.

Comment: Finger slipped? 2nd for -> or

Answer (score 1):

First of all replace  **`:`**  with **`;`** in the first for loop like this(you have used  wrong syntax)

```
for(initialize variable ; condition ; counter){}
```

and the second one is the enhanced for loop,

```
for(String s : str){.....}
```

quite handy in case of the collections,It does not require any counter because it runs till it reaches the last element in the collection provided to it(In this case `str` is that collection)

See this to learn more about it **[What is the syntax of enhanced for loop in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685305/what-is-the-syntax-of-enhanced-for-loop-in-java)**

Comment: also called a foreach loop, needs an Iterable class in order to use it

Answer (score 0):

Your definitive source for this sort of questions is the Java Language Specification. In this particular case:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14

A more friendly source may be found in the official Java Tutorials, in this case:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html