# Java looping through integer array

Tags: java, arrays

Consider the following Java code:

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
for(int i : array) {
    System.out.print(i + " ");
}
```

The above code obviously prints the contents of the array.

> 1 2 3 4 5

My question is why doesn't Java allow this?

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
int i;
for(i : array) {
    System.out.print(i + " ");
}
```

EDIT:
when I compile the 2nd program, I get the following error:

```
Main.java:14: error: bad initializer for for-loop
        for(i : array) {
            ^
1 error
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann:  That article doesn't address his problem at all --- it only covers the `Iterable` interface, specifically forgetting to `implements` it.  The [Java 1.5.0 "For-Each Loop" docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) it links to also don't mention it, although all their examples match his first version, they don't rule out his second.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because Java forces you to declare a variable here.  The [JLS, Section 14.14.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2), defines the enhanced `for` loop with syntax:

> EnhancedForStatement:
>
> ```
> for ( {VariableModifier} UnannType VariableDeclaratorId : Expression ) Statement
> ```
>
> EnhancedForStatementNoShortIf:
>
> ```
> for ( {VariableModifier} UnannType VariableDeclaratorId : Expression ) StatementNoShortIf
> ```

The `UnannType` is a type for the variable being declared.

It goes on to state that such an enhanced for loop is the equivalent of this, for looping over `Iterable`s...

```
for (I #i = Expression.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
    {VariableModifier} TargetType Identifier =
        (TargetType) #i.next();
    Statement
}
```

... and for arrays...

```
T[] #a = Expression;
L1: L2: ... Lm:
for (int #i = 0; #i < #a.length; #i++) {
    {VariableModifier} TargetType Identifier = #a[#i];
    Statement
}
```

It's clear that the variable is a locally declared variable inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

What is the error showing? Maybe you should initialize the varible:

```
int i = 0;
```

Comment: Primitives are initialized automatically with "0". The `for`-loop also changes the value of that `int` right away, so initializing that variable does not change anything.

Comment: @GiantTree no, local variables are not automatically initialized. But yes, this doesn't matter here.

Comment: Main.java:14: error: bad initializer for for-loop
      for(i : array) {
      ^
    1 error

Answer (score 0):

You are using “Enhanced” for-loops. This is a feature available after Java 1.5. The syntax of enhanced for loop is

```
for(Object obj : List) {
    ...
}
```

If you write in other format it will throw a compilation error. Basically the code you wrote is syntactically incorrect. This will be a compilation error.

You can refer
[What is the syntax of enhanced for loop in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685305/what-is-the-syntax-of-enhanced-for-loop-in-java)

Comment: I understand that. I'm simply trying to understand the rationale behind the syntax.

Comment: Its the syntax. Thats the way it is. else how will java know that for given list the desired object

Comment: @ParthaBisoi  From the original question, Java could infer the type from the initial variable declaration -  int i; 
for(i : array) {   . i is declared as an integer