# Using a for loop and charAt(); to print letters of a string in alternating cases

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class BugFixes
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        altCaps("Computer Science");
    }

    static void altCaps(String hi)
    {
        String hi2 = hi;
        int locate = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < hi2.length();i++)
        {
            if((Character.isLetter(hi2.charAt(locate))))
            {
                if(hi2.charAt(locate) % 2 == 0)
                {
                    System.out.print(hi2.toLowerCase().charAt(locate));
                    locate++;                   
                }
                else if(hi2.charAt(locate) % 2 == 1)
                {
                    System.out.print(hi2.toUpperCase().charAt(locate));
                    locate++;
                }                
            }
            else if(hi2.charAt(locate) == ' ')
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
                 locate++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is one of the problems that I have on my current lab. I was able to fix a few other mistakes but I can't seem to find this one.

My question is why it is outputting "COMpUtER SCIEnCE"? I don't understand what is happening here and I've been looking through it for an hour now. My goal is to output "CoMpUtEr ScIeNcE"

I thought the (hi2.charAt(locate) % 2 == 0) and vice versa would alternate between the even and odd locations in the string, but I believe I have made a mistake somewhere. I just can't find it.

Using BlueJ V3.1.7

1 year high school Computer Science Experience and currently enrolled in AP Computer Science

Any Tips?

Comment: You should start to learn how to debug a program. Then you can look step-by-step what output is produced and, looking at the state of your program, find programming bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you don't need to reassign the string, or the locate variable, or check if a character is already a character. Just use the iteration integer, if you need it, and the parameter.

Secondly, you're modding the character, not the position.

Anyways, a simple boolean toggle would be easier to understand than modding.

```
void altCaps(String hi) {
    boolean caps = true;
    for (char ch : hi.toCharArray()) {
        if (ch == ' ') {
            System.out.print(ch);
        } 
        else if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {
            if (caps) System.out.print(Character.toUpperCase(ch));
            else System.out.print(Character.toLowerCase(ch));
            caps = !caps;  // switch between upper and lower every character 
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, that does work. but due to my lower level of Java knowledge I don't exactly understand

for(char ch : hi.toCharArray()){
          if (ch == ' ') {
  What is 'ch'? What is the function of the Colon?

And what does "caps = !caps;" do?

Comment: First question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685305/what-is-the-syntax-of-enhanced-for-loop-in-java second question : it assigns the boolean to the negated value of itself

Answer (score 1):

not really. So `hi2.charAt(locate) % 2 == 0` is actually checking if the integer value of the character is odd or even, but you want to actually check if the index is odd or even if I get you right. In other words:

```
hi2.charAt(2) % 2 == 0
```

Is check if `m` is odd or even. However, I think you want to check if `2` (the index) is odd or even. I guess from here it's easy to assume that you need to change:

```
if(hi2.charAt(locate) % 2 == 0)
   //...
else if(hi2.charAt(locate) % 2 == 1)
   //...
```

to

```
if(locate % 2 == 0)
   //...
else if(locate % 2 == 1)
   //...
```

This won't give you exactly the output you want, but it's just a matter of inverting the `if` conditions or the body as you wish. Also, there's no other cases for the operation `% 2`, meaning you'd only get either an odd or even index, so you could simplify the code by just doing:

```
if(locate % 2 == 0)
   //...
else
   //...
```

Which reads better. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly advise refactoring your code to reduce repetative calls, and make inspection of values possible (rather than comparison of function evaluation).

For example:

```
char currentCharacter = hi2.charAt(locate);
```

would replace four instances of the function call, and allow you to inspect what the *actual* value is (rather than what you *expect* the value to be). This would likely make your error more evident.

Assuming the following values:

```
hi2 = "Computer Science";
locate = 0;
```

then it may be worth stepping through the evaluation.

```
0. hi2.charAt(locate) % 2 == 0
1. "Computer Science".charAt(0) % 2 == 0
2. 'C' % 2 == 0
3. 67 % 2 == 0
4. 1 == 0
5. false
```

The fundamental problem is that by never assigning your value to a variable, you never take the time to understand what is in it. By assigning it to the variable, you are able to inspect the value using a debugger.

By inspecting the values, we can see that you probably want the mod of `0`, not `'C'`, therefore you probably wanted

```
0. locate % 2 == 0
1. 0 % 2 == 0
2. 0 == 0
3. true
```

**Bonus**

Refactoring your code to reduce repetition, would also highlight other errors. For example, try the following:

```
assert  "CoMpUtEr sCiEnCe".equals(BugFixes.altcaps("Computer Science"));
assert  "CoMpUtEr-sCiEnCe 201".equals(BugFixes.altcaps("Computer-Science 201"));
```

KISS: removal of needless logic would reduce the chance of things going wrong.

Comment: I think `i` should be used instead of `locate`

Comment: @cricket_007 depenends on whether we are supposed to skip whitespace in the capitalization count. I think there is another defect that may become more apparent later, and requires `locate` for the fix