# How do I convert this for loop into enhanced for loop?

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

I´m struggling with making enhanced for loop from this regular for loop. I want each element of my `String ArrayList` to be equal to its value + " done"

```
for (int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); i ++)
{
    stringList.set(i, stringList.get(i) + " done");
}
```

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the syntax of enhanced for loop in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685305/what-is-the-syntax-of-enhanced-for-loop-in-java)

Comment: You can't/shouldn't replace the value in a specific position with it. If you only do a `List.get`, this is fine, but `List.set` is a problem.

Comment: ***Why*** do you want to replace the code above with an enhanced `for`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder is right here, classic example of XY problem...

Answer (score 3):

You can't use an enhanced for loop for this.

Either continue to use your existing code (which is fine for a `RandomAccess` list), or use `List.replaceAll`:

```
stringList.replaceAll(s -> s + " done");
```

Or, if you're still stuck on a pre-Java 8 version, use the code in the [Java 8 Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-):

```
 final ListIterator<String> li = stringList.listIterator();
 while (li.hasNext()) {
     li.set(li.next() + " done");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can* replace it with an enhanced `for`, but it's not really a good use of it:

```
int i = 0;
for (String s : stringList)
{
    stringList.set(i++, s + " done");
}
```