# Need to verify half of a String in a Loop

Tags: for-loop, kotlin, palindrome

I'm doing a palindrome exercise and want to verify half of the string in a loop. I tried to do for ex: ***for(index in text.indices / 2)*** and didn't work

```
fun palindrome(text:String): Boolean {

   var inverse : Int = text.length - 1

   for (index in text.indices) {
       if (!text[index].equals(text[inverse])) {
           return false
       }
       inverse--
   }
   return true
}
```

Comment: What °didn't work"? Is the result wrong, is it a compilation error (I can see a typo `inverso` instead of `inverse`), ...?

Comment: Ignore it, I was just translating when I posted the code. The problem that I want to solve is how can I divide for 2 the text length on for syntax... In java I did this for(int i = 0; i < texto.length()/2; i++), and I want to know how to do it on Kotlin...

Comment: Of course, you don't actually need a loop at all to write this particular function; you can do it with the one-liner: `fun isPalindrome(text: String) = text == text.reversed()`.  But that wouldn't give you practice in writing loops :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop syntax in Kotlin is similar to Java's ["enhanced for" loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685305/what-is-the-syntax-of-enhanced-for-loop-in-java):

```
for (<variable> in <expression>) {
    <body>
}
```

where `<expression>` can be "anything that provides an iterator" ([from the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#for-loops))

The Kotlin equivalent of the code you added in your comment is: `for (i in 0 until text.length()/2)`. Note that `until` is not a keyword but rather an [`infix` function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/until.html) and creates the [range](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html) `0 .. text.length()-1`.

More on ranges [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html).

Comment: Thanks, for(index in 0 until text.length/2) worked for me